# Why do we need Composite node?

Tags: compositing-nodes

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml1Kic4VopA - I watched this video and wondered - why Composite node exists? What is it for and what does it do? After all, we can work through a viewer node and export the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Composite node is where the actual output from the compositor is connected to the renderer. Connecting a node to the Composite node will output the result of that node's full tree to the Renderer, leaving this node unconnected will result in a blank image. This node is updated after each render, but also if you change things in your node-tree (provided at least one finished input node is connected)**

**The Viewer node is a temporary, in-process viewer. It can be plug in anywhere to inspect an image or value map in your node tree.**

From this you can say that the compositor node exist for the sole purpose of applying the composition to the render while viewer node is mainly used to see specific result of a certain group of nodes as well as it can do the job of a compositor node.

To further explain it:

The problem with the viewer node is that you will have to go into the Render Output panel and would have to select the viewer node to be displayed in it . And then you are free to save it. In highly detailed scenes we will be forced to make multiple renders , improving it gradually . That is where the [Composite node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/composite.html) comes to help - You wouldn't have to select the viewer node each time and save it.

Blender automatically composites a render if it's connected to a Composite node and will give you the finished result instantaneously. And that is the easiest way to put it...

[image]

You can also switch between Composite and View Layer as shown in here:-

[image]

Comment: Is the node only needed for the render to be immediately loaded into the composite node editor?

Comment: @White Raven ,I have edited my answer. Hope that answer your question.

Comment: I'll try to simplify the definition of this node - it should be just for show, so that the renders can be safely loaded into the composer right away. That is, in a sense, this node does the same thing as the checkbox in the item "Use nodes"

Comment: What do you think? Does this definition fit? I'm trying to figure out if I understood the answer correctly

Comment: I think I get it, the composite node is the output for the render layers. Is this definition close to the truth?

Comment: @White Raven, as i told in the answer the viewer nodes main purpose is viewing image as the backdrop. It can also be used to view a particular part of the compositing (like if creating a mask). It can be also used to save image by a hotkey Alt + S to save the output on viewer node

Comment: While compositor node's sole purpose is applying the composited result to the image instantly.

Comment: Happy that I could help you : )

Comment: You are cool, thank you for helping me figure it out)

Comment: When you asked the question I started reserching on this topic and I finally made up this answer. I learned a lot from this question . Thanks to you : )

Answer (score 0):

The *Viewer* node is there so that you can see the result of your node tree in the backdrop.

The *Composite* node result is not visible in Backdrop, for that you need to actually render, and if you don't use the *Composite* node when you render the whole node tree wont be used and will not actually be applied to your scene.

Comment: Am I right if I say that the Composite node stores the result of the previous render? And if the Render layer is disconnected from the Composite node after creating a new render, will the previous render result simply be erased and lost, being replaced by a new render?

Comment: @White Raven, The composite node won't store anything. I don't know what you mean by disconnecting the Render Layer node as it is the primary input of the compositor nodes unless you use another Input node.

Comment: The composite node won't store the results because the Render Layer node will update as you make a new render and the previous render will be lost completely as far as I can tell.